# How do i delete everything of specified "name"

Tags: kali-linux, command, locate, delete

A few days ago I installed `pcsxr` and today I wanted to completely remove everything of `pcsxr`

I tried to `purge` it but when I execute `locate -c pscxr` the output was `48` so it means I still have a folder/directory/content on my system. I want to know if there's any way that I can remove everything of `pcsxr`. Is there any way that I could just specify `name` and delete everything?

Comment: @ivanivan i think i installed from `synaptyc` but if it's same `apt get-install` process I'm not sure. I'll try to `apt autoremove`. Thanks. But is there anything that could perform such thing to specify `name` and delete everything of that `name`?

Comment: Yes, you could use a find command with the delete option or the exec option - `find / -iname *pscxr* -exec rm -rf {} \;` - but the package tools should have done it for you.  Do the `updatedb` process and see if locate still finds them

Answer (score 3):

Could be several causes, and it also depends on how you installed it.

First, the `locate` database is generated on a schedule via `cron`.  If you create a file, update the database via `updatedb`, delete the file you just created, and then try to `locate` it, it will still be in the database.  Regenerate the database with another run of `updatedb` and the file won't show in `locate`.

Secondly, if you installed it via `apt`, `apt-get`, etc. then `apt purge pscxr` or `apt-get purge pscxr` should do it, BUT it will only remove files that the install process created.  If you edit a file and your editor automatically creates a backup file, those backup files will still be there, as will the directory path to the files.  Note that if you needed other packages for dependencies, you'll need to also run `apt-get autoremove` or `apt autoremove`.

If you installed from source, if you have the source directory you ran the `make` commands in then you MIGHT be able to do a `make uninstall` BUT the success of that script would depend on the makefile itself.  Not a lot of source packages include a uninstall in the makefile though...

So... as root run `updatedb` then try your locate command, and unless you edited or copied files into the paths that are in the package it should all be gone...